# getting json from external source in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Json issues with javascript and jquery.
Trying to load some JSON using javascript.

I have it working using:

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/5pjha/789/

```
var url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true";

$.getJSON(url, function (json) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(json.results));
});
```

But it dosnt work on the following urls, why is this?

https://poloniex.com/public?command=return24hVolume

https://bittrex.com/api/v1/public/getmarkets

https://api.mintpal.com/v1/market/summary/

Are the following urls not correct JSON ?

Thanks

Comment: in alert you are using `json.results` which DOES exist in googleapis, but it does NOT exist in other JSONs.

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/ The validator says they are all valid. What is not working specifically? No results?

Comment: durrrrrrrrrr thanks.... i best remove this stupid question what a idiot, sometimes one overlooks such simple things

Answer (score 1):

The google's api set the **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** header to `*`, so you could access it by cross domain.

While other urls you provided do not, so you will got an error like below:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.mintpal.com/v1/market/summary/.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing for more details on why it doesn't work and how to use it.

Comment: I checked this one (https://poloniex.com/public?command=return24hVolume) and it has the header access-control-allow-origin: *

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is down to whether or not the servers you are requesting your JSON from have cross-origin resource sharing ([CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)) enabled.

you can see in the headers from the google service that they set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` This is not the case for teh other URL's you list.

To get around this you will need some form of proxy so that you can request from a server either on the same domain or a server that enables CORS.

Answer (score 0):

For ajax request to any server, You need to define Access-Control-Allow-Origin header for client. which is absent in given. You need to define origin of XMLHttp request in server who can request.

For more info refer this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)